# Apple watchOS 6.1 isBatteryMonitoringEnabled is not being set to true

Tags: watchkit, batterylevel, swift5, watchos-6

Swift nube here with Swift 5 on Xcode 11.  I am simply trying to get the status of my battery.  To do this I know I need to enable/set "isBatteryMonitoringEnabled" to true.  I enter the following line:

```
    WKInterfaceDevice.current().isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
```

I check the status with this:

```
    let watchBatteryMonitorStatus = WKInterfaceDevice.current().isBatteryMonitoringEnabled
    print("Battery Monitor Status: \(watchBatteryMonitorStatus)")
```

I get no warnings or errors during compilation, nor at run time.  But is NOT turning on the battery monitoring.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution?